# K-Means Implementation in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-science, k-means

Is it better to implement my own K-means Algorithm in Python or use the pre-implemented K-mean Algorithm in Python libraries like for example Scikit-Learn?

Comment: Depends on how you define "better". The library version will almost certainly be more efficient, but you could learn a lot doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering which is better, here is a quick reminder of the algorithm:

1. "Choose" the number of clusters **K**
2. Initiate your **first centroids**
3. For each point, find the **closest centroid**
   according to a distance function **D**
4. When all points are attributed to a cluster, calculate the **barycenter** of the cluster which become its new centroid
5. Repeat step 3. and step 4. until **convergence**

As stressed previously, the algorithm depends on various parameters:

- The number of clusters
- Your initial centroid positions
- A distance function to calculate distance between any point and centroid
- A function to calculate the barycenter of each new cluster
- A convergence metric
- ...

If none of the above is familiar to you, and you want to understand the role of each parameter, I would recommend to re-implement it on low-dimensional data-sets. Moreover, the implemented Python libraries might not match your specific requirements - even though they provide good tuning possibilities.

If your point is to use it quickly with a big-picture understanding, you can use existing implementation - scikit-learn would be a good choice.